# Git: two parallel branches with all files the same, except one different file (no .gitignore)

Tags: git

## Information

The front-end of my website has:

- branch production
- branch local
- a file vars.js

The file vars.js contains

```
var server = 'localhost:3000';
export {server};
```

I want my production branch to contain

```
var server = 'https://servername.com/';
export {server};;
```

## Question

#### Can I push to both branches, while keeping these files independent **without using .gitignore**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually have the following setup, a file for each environment, stored in each branch

- `vars.js` - local variables
- `vars.production.js` - production variables

Then my build process to deploy to production on CI/CD will replace vars.js with vars.production.js i.e. current build branch = production

One possible way to do it